# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property -- JQUERY for Stripe API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stripe-payments

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway on a webpage using the stripe API. I am referring to this code snippet [HERE](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/credit-card-payment-with-stripe). I am having trouble with loading JQUERY and kind of been struggling for some time to get it working. I am getting this ***error***

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addMethod' of undefined
```

I think the problem is because of not loading the jquery properly but not sure where its going wrong.

***code***

```
    <head>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

        <style>
            /* Padding - just for asthetics on Bootsnipp.com */
            body { margin-top:20px; }

            /* CSS for Credit Card Payment form */
            .panel-title {display: inline;font-weight: bold;}
            .checkbox.pull-right { margin: 0; }
            .pl-ziro { padding-left: 0px; }
            .form-control.error {
                border-color: red;
                outline: 0;
                box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.075),0 0 8px rgba(255,0,0,0.6);
            }
            label.error {
              font-weight: bold;
              color: red;
              padding: 2px 8px;
              margin-top: 2px;
          }
          .payment-errors {
              font-weight: bold;
              color: red;
              padding: 2px 8px;
              margin-top: 2px;
          }
        </style>
    </head>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title"><img class="pull-right" src="http://i76.imgup.net/accepted_c22e0.png">Payment Details</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <form role="form" id="payment-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cardNumber">CARD NUMBER</label>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="cardNumber" placeholder="Valid Card Number" required autofocus data-stripe="number" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-7 col-md-7">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="expMonth">EXPIRATION DATE</label>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 pl-ziro">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="expMonth" placeholder="MM" required data-stripe="exp_month" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-6 pl-ziro">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="expYear" placeholder="YY" required data-stripe="exp_year" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-5 col-md-5 pull-right">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="cvCode">CV CODE</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cvCode" placeholder="CV" required data-stripe="cvc" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="couponCode">COUPON CODE</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="couponCode" />
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Start Subscription</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row" style="display:none;">
                            <div class="col-xs-12">
                                <p class="payment-errors"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
var $form = $('#payment-form');
$form.on('submit', payWithStripe);

/* If you're using Stripe for payments */
function payWithStripe(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    /* Visual feedback */
    $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Validating <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');

    var PublishableKey = 'mykey'; // Replace with your API publishable key
    Stripe.setPublishableKey(PublishableKey);
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
        console.log
        if (response.error) {
            /* Visual feedback */
            $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Try again');
            /* Show Stripe errors on the form */
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
            $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').show();
        } else {
            /* Visual feedback */
            $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Processing <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse"></i>');
            /* Hide Stripe errors on the form */
            $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').hide();
            $form.find('.payment-errors').text("");
            // response contains id and card, which contains additional card details
            var token = response.id;
            console.log(token);
            // AJAX
            $.post('/account/stripe_card_token', {
                    token: token
                })
                // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
                .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $form.find('[type=submit]').html('Payment successful <i class="fa fa-check"></i>').prop('disabled', true);
                })
                .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $form.find('[type=submit]').html('There was a problem').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
                    /* Show Stripe errors on the form */
                    $form.find('.payment-errors').text('Try refreshing the page and trying again.');
                    $form.find('.payment-errors').closest('.row').show();
                });
        }
    });
}

/* Form validation */
jQuery.validator.addMethod("month", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^(01|02|03|04|05|06|07|08|09|10|11|12)$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid 2-digit month.");

jQuery.validator.addMethod("year", function(value, element) {
  return this.optional(element) || /^[0-9]{2}$/.test(value);
}, "Please specify a valid 2-digit year.");

validator = $form.validate({
    rules: {
        cardNumber: {
            required: true,
            creditcard: true,
            digits: true
        },
        expMonth: {
            required: true,
            month: true
        },
        expYear: {
            required: true,
            year: true
        },
        cvCode: {
            required: true,
            digits: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('success').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-control').removeClass('error').addClass('success');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        $(element).closest('.form-group').append(error);
    }
});

paymentFormReady = function() {
    if ($form.find('[name=cardNumber]').hasClass("success") &&
        $form.find('[name=expMonth]').hasClass("success") &&
        $form.find('[name=expYear]').hasClass("success") &&
        $form.find('[name=cvCode]').val().length > 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

$form.find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled', true);
var readyInterval = setInterval(function() {
    if (paymentFormReady()) {
        $form.find('[type=submit]').prop('disabled', false);
        clearInterval(readyInterval);
    }
}, 250);


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that:

You are trying to use [this jquery validation plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) without including it to your page.

add this to your page

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/g0qyzrdt/)

Comment: @user3342812 I added a working demo you can compare your code with it